# Preparing a product list but UI is not correct

Tags: html, css, angular

I have created a product list menu with a hover dropdown i.e when a user hovers on a particular menu the list will automatically be shown. 
But there are 2 problems first is I want to divide the vegetable dropdown menu into 3 columns. 
Secondly, when I hover correctly in between vegetable and spices dropdown menu the dropdown menu of both vegetables and spices starts shaking.

I am not getting the actual problem why is this happening.
please help.
I am Uploading the stackblitz link because the code is huge.

[This is the link for the actual code on StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-e8dney)

[This is the link to see the output of my code](https://angular-e8dney.stackblitz.io)

Answer (score 1):

1) For your .column css, your width is set to 50% which signifies a maximum value of up to 2 columns per row. If you alter that value to 33%, you will be able to fit up to 3 columns per row. This is at line 57 inside your app.component.css file.

2) The shaking is occurring because the window width is changing when you hover over vegetable because of the scroll bar being activated. When that happens your current cursor position thinks that its in between of both vegetables and spices at the same time, creating the shaking effect and alternating between the drop down menus.

Comment: @Orbit Your welcome make sure you upvote the answer! Happy to help.